# How can I remove all file associations for Office 2007 without uninstalling it?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, file-association

How can I remove all file associations for Microsoft Office 2007 without uninstalling it?

In addition, is it possible to install Office 2007 and not create any file associations?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in windows 7, open your start menu and click on "Default Programs". Now click on "Associate a file type...".

From here you can remap, but not remove, any file associations. [Here is a list of Office 2007 file extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007_file_extensions), which will come in handy.

If you want completely unassociate a filetype, you must use a third party tool, or delve into the registry. I prefer this [little freeware tool called unassoc](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/231/1/An-Utility-to-Unassociate-File-Types-in-Windows-7-and-Vista.html).

Comment: Are there any command line tools for both win xp and win 7 to do same thing as unassoc ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Back up `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` before you install, then restore those keys after install. That should reset your file extensions
2. Do what Paul said and delete them after install. This is a much safer option. Additionally [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com) is a point and click option to delete Default Programs associations.